# How to convert a table in a matrix in KNIME?

Tags: matrix, knime

Is it possible and if so, how to convert a table to a matrix?

My output table is structured as follows:

```
rowid   user   item   value
  0      x      A      10
  1      x      B      15
  2      x      C      0
  3      y      A      12
  4      y      B      17
  5      y      C      25
```

My goal is to create a matrix in the following form:

```
rowid    A    B    C
  x      10   15   0
  y      12   17   25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Pivoting](https://hub.knime.com/knime/extensions/org.knime.features.base/latest/org.knime.base.node.preproc.pivot.Pivot2NodeFactory) node with the following settings:

**Group column(s)**  `user`

**Pivot column(s)** `item`

**Manual Aggregation > Column** `value`

**Advanced Settings > Column name:** `Pivot name`

You can leave the Aggregation set to `First`.

Connect the `Pivot table` output to a [RowID](https://hub.knime.com/knime/extensions/org.knime.features.base/latest/org.knime.base.node.preproc.rowkey2.RowKeyNodeFactory2) node with settings:

**Replace RowID with…** checked

**New RowID column** `user`

**Remove selected column** checked

[image: screenshot]